# sklearn.metrics Prevent unlabeled predictions from being classified as false positives

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a multiclass, single label classifier which predicts some samples as `"-1"`, which means that it is not confident enough to assign the sample a label. I would like to use `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support` to calculate the metrics for the model, however I am unable to prevent the `"-1"` classifications from being considered as false positives.

The only thing I can think of is to do this on a "per class" basis for the metrics then do a weighted-average over the metrics excluding the `"-1"` class (i.e. the `micro` option in `precision_recall_fscore_support` while excluding `"-1"` false positives).

Is there any standardized way to do this in sklearn without having to compute the averages myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. The `labels` parameter of `precision_recall_fscore_support` allows you to specify which labels you desire to use. Therefore, by using `labels=list(set(y_true).union(set(y_pred)).difference(set(["-1"])))`

I am able to obtain the desired behavior.